# sql Create a Index ID as a new column to sort the case categories i just created Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing, case

I'd like to create a SortID column to sort the results in different case categories. Each case category represents a revenue range. I grouped by the results on the case statements to get how many orders for each case. Now I am stuck with this SortID creating issue. Below please find my current query. Please suggest me where i can put the index creation statement in my query.Many thanks in advance!

```
select SalesAmountCategory, count(*) as Orders 
from
    (Select case
            when ((SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=100000) then '>$100000'
            when ((SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=50000) then '$50000-$100000'
            when ((SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=10000) then '$10000-$50000'
            when ((SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=5000) then '$5000-$10000'
            when ((SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=2500) then '$2500-$5000'
            when ((SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=1000) then '$1000-$2500'
            when ((SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=500) then '$500-$1000'
            when ((SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=100) then '$100-$500'
            when ((SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)<100) then '$0-$100'
            end as SalesAmountCategory
        From  dbo.FactResellerSales 
        where OrderDate BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2010-12-31 23:59:59.999'
    ) as t
    group by SalesAmountCategory
    order by SalesAmountCategory;
```

Below please find the image as a expected result example

[image: Result Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `apply` instead of sub-query, you can use `row_number` to create `sortid` :

```
select row_number() over (order by min(SalesAmount - TaxAmt - Freight)) as sortid,
       SalesAmountCategory, count(*) as Orders
from dbo.FactResellerSales frs cross apply
     ( values (case when (SalesAmount - TaxAmt - Freight) >= 100000 then '>$100000'
                    when (SalesAmount - TaxAmt - Freight) >= 50000) then '$50000-$100000'
                    . . .
                    when (SalesAmount - TaxAmt - Freight) < 100 then '$0-$100'
               end)
     ) frss(SalesAmountCategory)
where OrderDate BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2010-12-31 23:59:59.999'
group by SalesAmountCategory;
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. But still no new index column like SortID in my example has been created.

Comment: @vivianna. . . I missed that part. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ordering by the category, order by the minimum amount in each category:

```
select row_number() over (order by min(SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)) as sortid,
. . . 
order by min(SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)
```

Of course, you will need to select these columns as well in the subquery (or do the calculation in the subquery).

Comment: many thanks. But still don't know how to create a new column like SortID in my example

Comment: @vivianna . . . I didn't realize that was part of your question.  You just use `row_number()` with the same `order by` expression.  You don't need to create such a column in order to sort the result set.